# Why do alcohols not undergo resonance?

Tags: resonance

Take for example $\ce{CH3OH}$. The lone pair on the oxygen atom may be donated to form a double bond and giving $\ce{CH3-}$ and $\ce{O+}$ ?
Is it because we cant have + charge on $\ce{O}$ atom?

Comment: Octet rule is broken on the carbon.

Comment: Please tell me do you the conditions for resonance to take place!!

Comment: To see a similar substance that can undergo resonance, look at phenol. (Alcohols like [vinyl alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_alcohol) really overdo it, they isomerize to aldehydes).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I misread the question which meant the structure 
$\ce{H_3C- =O^+-H}$ rather than $\ce{H_3C^- O^+}$ which I assumed previously. This structure is not possible because the carbon atom's octet is violated, as it has 10 electrons around itself. Carbon should always have an octet structure (if possible) or lesser number of electrons (like in carbocations) in the resonance contributor structures.

Comment: O would still have 8 el. but C gets 10 and that's the problem

Comment: oh sorry I shall edit.I got confused by the CH3- O+ part in the question

Comment: @Mithoron I have edited my answer.

Comment: You'd better integrate those parts, You don;t have to use this EDIT convention.